# Spring integration flow respond with HTTP 400

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a spring integration flow that expects a "routingkey" message header. If this is not present I'd like to send a HTTP 400 response back to the client. How can I do that? Below you will see the determineRoutingKey method is where I can determine whether the routing key was passed as a header.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow webToRabbit(RabbitTemplate amqpTemplate)
{
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from
            (
                Http.inboundGateway("/tunnel")
                    .replyTimeout(Integer.valueOf(timeout))
                    .mappedRequestHeaders("*")
                    .mappedResponseHeaders("*")
            )
            .log()
            .handle
            (
                Amqp.outboundGateway(amqpTemplate)
                    .exchangeName(exchangeName)
                    .routingKeyFunction(f->determineRoutingKey(f))
                    .mappedRequestHeaders("*")
                    .mappedReplyHeaders("*")
            )
            .log()
            .bridge(null)
            .get();
}

private String determineRoutingKey(Message<?> message) 
{
    MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
    if(headers.containsKey(HEADER_ROUTINGKEY))
    {
        String routingKey = Objects.toString(headers.get(HEADER_ROUTINGKEY));
        log.debug("Using routing key: " + routingKey);
        return routingKey;
    }
    else
    {
        log.error("Headers found: " + Objects.toString(headers));

        //Here I get an exception stating that MessageHeaaders is immutable
        message.getHeaders().put(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logic like:

```
private HttpStatus resolveHttpStatusFromHeaders(MessageHeaders headers) {
    Object httpStatusFromHeader = headers.get(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE);
    return buildHttpStatus(httpStatusFromHeader);
}
```

So, what you need is just regular (string with error message?) reply and an appropriate `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` as a `http_statusCode` header.

No reason in any exceptions.

**UPDATE**

Since you are in the middle of the flow and it is still far away from the reply, you can stick with that exception approach.

What you have to do there to return proper 400 response is an `errorChannel` on the `Http.inboundGateway()` and some simple transformer to returns a `Message` with an appropriate `HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` header:

```
Http.inboundGateway("/tunnel")
    .errorChannel("httpErrorFlow.input")
...

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpErrorFlow() {
    return f -> f
            .<RuntimeException, Message<?>>transform(payload -> {
                if (payload.getCause() instanceof MyRoutingKeyException) {
                    return MessageBuilder.withPayload("Bad routing key")
                            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                            .build();
                }
                throw payload;
            });
}
```

But again: you can't just throw an exception.

That is

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your answer.

Comment: The `HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport` can properly resolve status code from headers and use reply `payload` as a body for response. You don't need to throw any exception. Otherwise it is just only `500`. You have to populates reply manually and add `HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` to the reply message in that wrong case.

Comment: Well, you can throw exception, but you have to add `errorChannel` to the `Http.inboundGateway()` to convert that exception to the proper reply with an `HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` header for `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` value.

Comment: If I don't throw an exception here then there is no routing key returned in the determineRoutingKey function. At that point I don't know how to route the message. I'm not seeing how the framework is going to somehow detect that.

Comment: I just updated my code using what I think you were first suggesting. I tried to put an http status code in the headers of the message but it says those headers are immutable and throws a 500. The error channel route looks pretty involved and I'm not sure what other implications that would have over the system if I have a custom error channel. There must be a best practice for handling this simple situation.

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.